# Algebra on a Louvre tablet

Tags: algebra-precalculus, math-history

**Problem:** On a Louvre tablet of about 300 B.C. are four problems concerning rectangles of unit area and given semiperimeter. Let the sides and semiperimeter be $x,y$ and $a$. Then we have
\begin{equation}
xy=1, \qquad x+y=a. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Solve this system by using the identity
$$
\biggl(\frac{x-y}{2}\biggr)^2 = \biggl(\frac{x+y}{2}\biggr)^2 - xy \tag{2}
$$
**Attempted solution:**

*By elimination:* To eliminate $y$, we note that $y = \frac{1}{x}$, and we substitute this $y$-value into the equation $x+y=a$ to obtain
$$
x = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2-4}}{2},
$$
where this solution was obtained by using the quadratic formula.

*By using the given identity:* Start by letting $y=a-x$. Using this and the fact that $x+y=a$, we have the following:
\begin{align*}
\biggl(\frac{2x-a}{2}\biggr)^2 = \biggl(\frac{a}{2}\biggr)^2 - 1 &\longleftrightarrow 4x^2-4xa+a^2 = a^2-4\\ &\longleftrightarrow x^2-ax+1=0,
\end{align*}
whereby we get that $x = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}$, as we did above by using elimination.

**Main question:** My solution using (2) seems to *work*, but is there a "slicker" approach? That is, it seems like the originally posed problem wants me to do something nifty with (2) rather than using it in such a brutish fashion. Anyone have a cleaner approach in mind in regards to solving (1) by using (2)?

Comment: @Micah Just so you know--this problem actually appeared as Problem Study 2.4 in Howard Eves' *An Introduction to the History of Mathematics*; the title for that problem study is "Algebraic Geometry".

Comment: Algebraic geometry can be used to mean many things : from the use of cartesian coordinates in a plan geometry problem to scheme theory and étale cohomology. On MSE, it is reserved for problems about curves, varieties, scheme, etc. This is too elementary to be tagged (algebraic-geometry).

Comment: [Geometric algebra](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_elementary_algebra#Greek_geometric_algebra) would have been a correct tag (but not the tag geometric algebras, which dels with Clifford algebras!). The equation (2) above is essentially [Euclid II.8](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookII/propII8.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the intended solution was as follows:
$$
\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-1.
$$
Thus $x-y$ can be solved for:
$$
x-y=\pm2\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2-1}=\pm\sqrt{a^2-4}
$$ Adding and subtracting with $x+y$ gives us:
$$
x=\frac{(x+y)+(x-y)}{2}=\frac{a\pm \sqrt{a^2-4}}{2},
$$
and likewise for $y$.

*Note that this is a re-derivation of the quadratic formula; in particular, it defeats the purpose of this approach to **use** it!*

Comment: Is your last note a criticism of my approach using (2)? If so, it is well-taken--I certainly did not think my way of using (2) was any good. It seems even my solution to (1) using elimination *should* have ended (keeping the historical context in mind) with simply writing $x^2-ax+1=0$. Thoughts?

Comment: What I meant was that in both your solutions, you appear to be applying the quadratic equation at some stage. However, we can use the identity (2) as an alternative to the quadratic equation, and actually re-derive the quadratic equation using this method.

Comment: Once you reduce to $x^2-ax+1=0$, you still need to solve for $x$. And this is the whole point of the problem; either you use the quadratic equation or you use something else. Does that help?

Comment: Oh yes--you are quite correct; I see it more clearly now. In the textbook this is in (Howard Eves' *Introduction to the History of Mathematics*), the original problem I posed is actually two problems: 1) Solve (1) by eliminating $y$ and obtain a quadratic in $x$, and 2) use the identity (2) to solve the quadratic obtained when using elimination. Given what you wrote, it all makes perfect sense now. Thanks!